# How can I fix a Discord python bot whose commands are not working

Tags: python, bots, discord

My bot was working fine yesterday. I made some changes in the code and when I run it, the bot would go online without any errors but no commands would work. I tried to use an old code that worked, but even that code doesn't work. I also regenerated the token and tried, but that did not work. Please help.

Here's my code:

```
import random
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')
client.remove_command('help')

TOKEN = ''


# Bot status
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Game('.help for commands!'))
    print("Bot is ready")


# Member join
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print(f'{member} has joined the server.')
    e = discord.Embed()
    e.set_image(url='https://i.imgur.com/zYexoRK.png')
    channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.channels, name="welcome")
    await channel.send(f"Welcome {member.mention}! :partying_face:", embed=e)


# Member leave
@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    print(f'{member} has left the server.')



# Ping command
@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"Ping is {round(client.latency * 1000)}ms")


# 8ball command
@client.command(aliases=['8ball', 'test'])
async def eball(ctx, *, question):
    responses = ['Absolutely.',
                 'Definitely not.',
                 'It is certain.',
                 'Not at all.',
                 'My sources say no',
                 'Not sure',
                 'Cannot predict now',
                 'Very doubtful',
                 "Don't count on it",
                 'Outlook not so good',
                 'Most likely',
                 'Without a doubt',
                 'As I see it, yes',
                 'You kidding me?',
                 "I don't answer stupid questions.",
                 'Ask again later.',
                 "Yes, but actually no.",
                 "Yes and no.",
                 "I'm no one to decide.",
                 ]
    await ctx.send(f'Question: {question}\nAnswer: {random.choice(responses)}')


# Clear command
@client.command()
async def clear(ctx, amount=5):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)


# Help command
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def help(ctx):
    channel = ctx.message.channel
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title='Commands',
        description='Commands',
        colour=discord.Colour.magenta()

    )

    embed.set_footer(text='@Takahashi | @deviantart.com/seerlight')
    embed.set_image(url='https://i.imgur.com/AVYIGjO.jpg')
    embed.set_thumbnail(url='https://i.pinimg.com/originals/ac/33/cb/ac33cba8c9df761dfcaa31e0e998af47.gif')
    embed.set_author(name='Takahashi', icon_url='https://i.imgur.com/j4SkgMo.png')

    embed.add_field(name='.help', value='Gives this message', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='.ping', value='Returns latency', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='.8ball', value='Returns answer to your dumb questions', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='.clear', value='Clear previous 5 lines', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='.flip', value='Randomly gives heads or tails', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='.about', value='Information about Takahashi and its developers', inline=False)
    await ctx.send(channel, embed=embed)


# Head and Tails
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def flip(ctx):
    flip = ['https://i.imgur.com/OqFNJO7.png',
            'https://i.imgur.com/DarGk5i.png', ]
    channel = ctx.message.channel
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title='Heads and tails',
        description='Randomly gives heads and tails',
        colour=discord.Colour.blurple()

    )

    embed.set_image(url=f'{random.choice(flip)}')
    embed.set_thumbnail(url='https://media.tenor.com/images/1dc6f800ad56428f0ac93ae57662a006/tenor.gif')
    embed.set_author(name='Takahashi', icon_url='https://i.imgur.com/j4SkgMo.png')

    await ctx.send(channel, embed=embed)


client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Just a heads-up, in rewrite you don't need to add in `pass_context=True`, as it is automatically passed for commands. On a side-note, is that all the code? Do you get any errors when running the commands? Or do you have an `on_message` event lying around somewhere? If so, add `await client.process_commands(message)`.

Comment: Try removing the `client.remove_command('help')` to see what commands are actually registered. Because it's a default command with every bot, it should work. You can add it back in after things start working though.

Answer (score 0):

when you applyed some changes, coud it be possible that you accidentaly regenerated the **bottoken** or that you accidentaly removed a caracter, like `DASFRE8894759` becomes `DASFRE884759` . the difference is hard to spot. Go to your discord developer portal and click **regenerate bot token** or **view bottoken** and copy paste the token just to be sure.

i hope i coud help